# The argument type 'FutureOr<void> Function(Database, int)' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'FutureOr<void> Function(Database, int)?'

Tags: flutter, function, dart, nullable, sqflite

[image]

This [ int = int? ] I understand it's an error,
but [ FutureOr<void> func() = FutureOr<void> func()? ]
I don't understand the difference between
func() and func()?
Please can anybody explain to me what's going on here?

Here is the problematic code:

```
        // create a getter to instantiate the database obj
         Future<Database> get database async {
        // initialize the database when uninitialized
         if (_database != null) return _database!;
           _database = await _initDB('students.db');
           return _database!;
         }
       Future<Database> _initDB(String filePath) async {
         final dbPath = await getDatabasesPath();
         final path = join(dbPath, filePath);
         return await openDatabase(path, version: 1, onCreate: _createDB);
       }
      FutureOr<void> _createDB(Database db, int version) async {
        const String idType = 'INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT';
        const String textType = 'TEXT NOT NULL';
        const String boolType = 'BOOLEAN NOT NULL';
        const String intType = 'INTEGER NOT NULL';
        const String telephoneType = 'INTEGER NOT NULL';
    
        const String studentID = 'StudentId';
        const String studentFirstName = 'studentFirstName';
        const String studentMiddleName = 'studentMiddleName';
        const String studentLastName = 'studentLastName';
        const String studentAge = 'studentAge';
        const String studentGender = 'studentGender';
        const String studentHometown = 'studentHometown';
    const String studentLocation = 'studentLocation';


    return await db.execute('''
      CREATE TABLE  Students(
        $studentID $idType,
        $studentFirstName $textType,
        $studentMiddleName $textType,
        $studentLastName $textType,
        $studentAge $intType,
        $studentGender $textType,
        $studentHometown $textType,
        $studentLocation $textType,
      )
      ''');
    }
```

Here's the image also for better syntax highlighting

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I believe you have to change the `_createdDB`, it's return type is `Future<void>` and you return the `db.execute` function. Just delete the `return` statement.

```
   FutureOr<void> _createDB(Database db, 
   int version) async {  
   await db.execute('''
      CREATE TABLE  Students(
        $studentID $idType,
        $studentFirstName $textType,
        $studentMiddleName $textType,
        $studentLastName $textType,
        $studentAge $intType,
        $studentGender $textType,
        $studentHometown $textType,
        $studentLocation $textType,
      )
      ''');
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you have to change these return types to nullable `Database?`

```
Future<Database?> get database async {
        // initialize the database when uninitialized
         if (_database != null) return _database!;
           _database = await _initDB('students.db');
           return _database!;
         }
       Future<Database?> _initDB(String filePath) async {
         final dbPath = await getDatabasesPath();
         final path = join(dbPath, filePath);
         return await openDatabase(path, version: 1, onCreate: _createDB);
       }
```